# Firestore get subcollection data with promises

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, promise

I'm trying to get the data from my subcollections, the things is I need to do it with Promises (If I don't, I can't get the data from the cache)

Here how I am actually doing :

```js
        bookStores = db.collection("bookstores");
        bookStores.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
             bookStoresIds.push(change.doc.id); // I use a list so a can iterate on IDs for subs
             // Doing stuff
          });

          bookStoresIds.forEach(bookStoreId => {
            const task = db.collection('bookstores').doc(bookStoreId).collection('books')
            task.onSnapshot((snapshotTask) => {
              snapshotTask.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
                // Doing stuff
              });
            });
          })
```

I use a list to store the IDs. This version works, but causes me some troubles and I want to use Promises.

Here what I tried :

```js
async function getBookStores(id,) {
  const bookStoreIds: string[] = [];

  db.collection("bookStores").onSnapshot({ includeMetadataChanges: true }, (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
     // Doing Stuff

    });
  });
  return bookStoreIds;
}

async function getBooks(bookStoreIds) {
  bookStoreIds.forEach(bookStoreId => {
    const book = db.collection('bookStores').doc(bookStoreId).collection('books')
    task.onSnapshot({ includeMetadataChanges: true }, (snapshotTask) => {
      snapshotTask.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
        // Doing Stuff
      });
    })
  })
}

getBookStores(id)
        .then((list) => {
          return getBooks(list);
        })
```

The problem is, when it cames to getBooks, the list is empty ... Is somebody have an idea ?

Comment: Snapshot listeners with onSnapshot aren't compatible with promises.  A promise represents a single operation that returns a single object.  Listeners can return many values over time, and you have to remove the listener to stop the query.

Comment: Now I read you, seems very logic ... ! Would you have an idea of how I could do ?